# asp.net web api return array of json objects with dynamic keys

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How do I return an array of json objects with dynamic keys, for example:

```
[
    "dynamic prop 1": {
          "title": "abc",
          "sku": "123"
        },
    "dynamic prop 2": {
          "title": "xyz",
          "sku": "789"
        }
]
```

The default formatting is:

```
[
        {
          "title": "abc",
          "sku": "123"
        },
        {
          "title": "xyz",
          "sku": "789"
        }
]
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the .NET dynamic type?

Comment: No. I just wanted to emphasize that the the property could be anything. For example, the title and sku are properties I know but the "key/name/id" of the object could be any string.

Comment: Understood, but you are constructing this object on the server. So you can use the dynamic type and return a JObject.

Comment: Yes, on the server. Currently I'm returning this: 
            return data.Select(x => new
            {
                title = x.title,
                sku = x.sku
            });

Comment: use a stringbuilder and simply build the json string which you want.

Comment: I was going to say use a JObject and convert ToString, but I don't think it will take a dynamic.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to do this? In your example you essentially have a list of typed objects... why not just return that list? What value does a random key that contains the objects as values add to your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JObject solved the problem:

```
JObject jProducts= new JObject();

foreach (var p in products)
{
    var o = new JObject()
    {
        { "title",  p.Title},
        { "sku", p.Sku }
    };

    jProducts.Add(p.Name, o);
}

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jProducts);
```

Thanks to william-xifaras

Answer (score 0):

Use return List of objects.
Where object (say **MyObj**)having properties: title and sku.
then yuo will get desired output.
Your data to be returned will look like:

```
List<MyObj> data=new List<MyObj>();
// add your objects.
// return this list object.
```

u will get you output in format you want.

Comment: That's incorrect. It's the default formatting which I am getting already.

Answer (score 0):

then return dynamic object.

```
return new{ property1Name=MyObj1,property2Name=MyObj2}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Otherwise refer following link to generate c# classes from json and create required model in ur solution.
[https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEl7efl_XNAhWJs48KHYDHAUsQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjson2csharp.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEbR-mTF-PU4BYWff3opCDcJOl0ag&bvm=bv.127178174,d.c2I](http://Json2CSharp)

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing but it does not solve the problem. The "property1Name" is a variable so I can't use the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Then You refer

```
Tuple data type and learn about it.
```

It may wotk for you.